# jquery exception

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this navmenu with anchors associated with a jquery snippet that loads in and animates content. (See demo: http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/011_jQuerySite/sample/index.html)

Now, on some of the nav's anchors, I'd like for this plugin to NOT fire off (as I want to be able to associate some of the navmenu's anchors strictly with the ScrollTo plugin instead).

My question is, what can I add to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('#nav li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-4)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.php #content';
        $('#content').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

$('#nav li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').hide(888,loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn(888);
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-4);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show(888,hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut(888);
    }
    return false;

});

});
```

...so that it doesn't fire off all the above whenever the anchor has the class="scroll" associated with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude anchors by using [`.not(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('#nav li a').not('.scroll').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-4)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.php #content';
        $('#content').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

$('#nav li a').not('.scroll').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').hide(888,loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn(888);
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-4);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show(888,hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut(888);
    }
    return false;

});

});
```